# How do you track click-to-call mobile?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile

How do you track click-to-call mobile clicks? What data can I pass about the phone/caller to my tracking system?

Comment: Maybe you make the link look like a click-to-call link, submit an ajax request, before altering the html and programatically clicking on it?